# Full page Static footer in twitter bootstrap 3.3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to create a full page static footer in twitter bootstrap like in [This](http://www.cyclelove.net/) website or in [This](http://www.digitaltutors.com/11/index.php) website. The footer in both website are almost 400px to 500px, and I want the same footer but static not fixed, the one I create is showing fixed I don't know where I mess-up the code. This is the jsfiddle [Link](http://jsfiddle.net/msz900/yp5ff0wc/) of what I try and below is my code...

Footer html code

```
<div class="footer affix clearfix">
gfh
</div>
```

Footer css

```
.footer
{

    bottom: 0;
    height: 400px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background: #222222;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to update your HTML and CSS to:

```
<div class="footer">gfh</div>

.footer {
    height: 400px;
    width: 100%;
    background: #222222;
}
```

Here's a Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/m0nk3y/yp5ff0wc/1/

You do not need "affix" unless you want it to be fixed position. Also, clearfix is not necessary unless you plan to float elements inside the `<div>`. There's no need for bottom, left, or right positioning since you plan to use the default position (which is 'static' by default).

I hope that helps. Good luck!